# python - search for a string and return the whole string which has the matched string or required data

Tags: python, parsing, search

I'm trying to search for something like this,

i/p :

```
FAILED: Exception thrown in login flow loginUser flow
FAILED: Arrayoutofbounds in create user CreateUser flow
PASSED: ForgetPassword flow is successful.
```

o/p:

```
FAILED:loginUser 
FAILED:CreateUser 
PASSED:ForgetPassword
```

Basically, im trying to fetch list of flows its failed and passed.

I tried this,

```
list = ['PASSED', 'SKIPPED', 'FAILED']

if all(word in output for word in list):
    print "Hey Word Found"
```

But the above snipped just returns if the word is found or not.

But i need to parse the flow name in the string, which matches any of them above.

Need some help in achieving this.

Comment: Is the flow-name always before the "flow" word? And is it always a single word?

Comment: Your works is always between `**`?

Comment: added by mistake. corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use regex.

```
>>> s = '''FAILED: Exception thrown in login flow **loginUser** flow
FAILED: Arrayoutofbounds in create user **CreateUser** flow
PASSED: **ForgetPassword** flow is successful.'''.splitlines()
>>> for line in s:
    m = re.search(r'^(' + '|'.join(lst) + r'):.*?\*\*([^*]*)', line)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1)+ ':' + m.group(2))


FAILED:loginUser
FAILED:CreateUser
PASSED:ForgetPassword
>>>
```

This `r'^(' + '|'.join(lst) + r'):.*?\*\*([^*]*)'` creates a regex which looks like `(PASSED|SKIPPED|FAILED):.*?\*\*([^*]*)`. So the first capturing group contains, `PASSED` or `SKIPPED` or `FAILED` and the seocnd groupo contains the chars which exists between two `**`

If there, is no `*` present then you could fetch the string which exists before `flow`.

```
m = re.search(r'^(' + '|'.join(lst) + r'):.*\s(\S+)\s+flow\b', line)
```

Comment: Does this method depend on the `**` in the string? My guess is that the OP used it for trying to show that in bold (not knowing it does not work inside the code block.)

Comment: @ Avinash : Thank you so much for the help. But, i would really appreciate if you explain it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj That would result in the first line giving `login` instead of `loginUser` , wouldn't it?

Comment: @ Avinash : The ** are given here by mistake, when i tried to put in bold. I edited the question again. can you please update your code accordingly.

Comment: @AnandSKumar ya, edited.. Logeshwari, check my update.

Comment: @ Avinash : could you please explain this                                                                                                                     m = re.search(r'^(' + '|'.join(lst) + r'):.*?\s(\S+)\s+flow\b', line).

Comment: `\S+` matches one or more non-space characters where `\s+` matches one or kmore space characters.